# Not able to delete items from flatList In react-native from Api,

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Not able to delete items from flatList In react-native from Api,ApiCard is another Component where the required data items are coming had a del button..

```
      import React, {Component} from 'react'; import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Button, } from 'react-native'; import ApiCard from './ApiCard';
    export default class ApiList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      dataSource: [],
    };
  }
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'List of countries',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
  }
  render() {
    const {dataSource} = this.state;
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={dataSource}
          keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          renderItem={data => (
            <ApiCard {...data.item} navigation={navigation} />

          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

> the Below component is for data rendering as props

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

const ApiCard = ({name, navigation, alpha2Code, population, capital}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.country}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.push('CountryName', {
          name,
          alpha2Code,
          population,
          capital,
        })
      }>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <Text>{alpha2Code}</Text>
      <Button title="del" /
```

> here i need a del button action
> its not deleting any thing and delete action didn't working

please help me finding solution
i tried all the methods but i'm not able to delete this

```
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default ApiCard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do more readings on React and JS. But one way to pass is to create a method/function to alter and update your data.

Snippet:
Sample is to do drilling, which is passing a method from parent to child.

```
//Assumption
const [datasource, setDataSource] = useState([])

//From your sample
const deleteItem = index => { 
   const arr = [...dataSource]; 
   arr.splice(index, 1); 
   setDataSource(arr); 
};

//You can use 'currying', meaning a partial function. 
onPressApiCard = (index) => () => {
   setLoading(true)
   deleteItem(index) //your index
} //method won't get executed until pressed as it's partial.

...
//pass index from data, see flatlist document
<FlatList
      data={dataSource}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      renderItem={data => (
<ApiCard {...data.item} navigation={navigation} onPressCallback={onPressApiCard(data.index)}/>
...
```

From your child(ApiCard) trigger it. In general, your child node will need to update the Parent Component.

```
//pass your data
const ApiCard = ({name, navigation, alpha2Code, population, capital, onPressCallback}) => 
//[Alternative], pass index here
//const ApiCard = ({name, navigation, alpha2Code, population, capital, onPressCallback, index}) => 
 ...
 return (
 <TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.country}
  onPress={() =>
    onPressCallback(); //Call the parent method
    //[Alternative] onPressCallback(index); //send index here.
    navigation.push('CountryName', {
      name,
      alpha2Code,
      population,
      capital,
    })
  }>
```

A note is that, you will not be able to delete a value stored in **state**. You are required to update a state than changing that value directly. Do read about react state lifting [state-lifting](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Getting more complex depending on need you will later need to check up on "Context","State management like redux/recoil"

Comment: Only the first element is deleting whether you click at any item,
delteitemData deletes only the first item..Below is the Code For deleting Items,
here I used splice method ..Please help me with the solution...

const deleteItem = index => {
    const arr = [...dataSource];

    arr.splice(index, 1);
    setDataSource(arr);
  };
  onPressApiCard = () => {
    setDataSource(index => {
      deleteItem(index);
    });
  };

Comment: @HemaSai, the method of deleteItem is correct. However "onPressApiCard = () => { setDataSource(index => { deleteItem(index); }); };" is ambigious. #1 where does you index comes from it seems to always pass 0.

Comment: @HemaSai update the codes. But may take you some time to digest, anyway your goal is to figure out how to send your "index" for deletion.

Comment: Is there any Solution for this Bug to be removed..???

Comment: @HemaSai it's not a bug it's a standard javascript. As because you need to pass parameters and onPress/onClick only sends Events as arguments. I know it's a lot to digest, but if you strengthen your JS more it's easier to absorb later on(i'm no expert either). :)

Comment: Btw hope the currying helps "onPressApiCard = (index) => () => " with your problem. Alternatively, you can pass index into ApiCard component, in that case you can use onPressApiCard directly because ApiCard calling method will send the index.

Comment: I'll try it for Sure